# How to call function with named parameter

Tags: swift

```
    public func write<Query: GraphQLQuery>(data: Query.Data, forQuery query: Query) throws {
      try write(object: data, withKey: Query.rootCacheKey, variables: query.variables)
    }
```

How do I call this function?  Several attempts have given me the compiler error: "incorrect argument labels in call (have 'data:forQuery:', expected 'object:withKey:')"

New to swift parameters I guess.

Comment: Is this function defined on a type or is it a free function? Please include examples of how you've tried to call it.

Comment: I am going to guess that since its a generic the compiler is having trouble inferring the type.  Make sure that your parameters match the method signature otherwise you get cryptic errors when the compiler cannot tell how to specialize the generic.

Comment: Please provide implementation for `GraphQLQuery` protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generic function that require second parameter (`query`) to conform `GraphQLQuery` protocol, which require associated type `Data`.

I don't know what requirements of this protocol and how it implemented. So let's assume for example:

```swift
protocol GraphQLQuery {
    associatedtype Data
}
struct MyQuery: GraphQLQuery {
    typealias Data = Int
}
let query = MyQuery()
try? write(data: 0, forQuery: query)

or

do {
    try write(data: 0, forQuery: query)
} catch { ... error handling }
```

So now to call function we need pass our query and data this query able to work with (`Int` in my example)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if, you have an argument in your function that is not defined "forQuery" isn't looking for any values to be passed through when the function is called this may be your problem.

Examples of how you are trying to call the function, would be useful to add to this question just as mentioned in a comment above. Information is a great tool for any developer looking to help answer your question!

Make sure all of your arguments are looking to get a value passed in when calling the function. Example :

```
public func write<Query: GraphQLQuery>(data: Query.Data, forQuery: pass in forQuery value here query: Query) throws {
      try write(object: data, withKey: Query.rootCacheKey, variables: query.variables)
    }
```